# How to store existing column value in new table using trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have two tables

- Customer
- CustomerUpdate

Structure of both tables are like this

**Customer** table's structure

```
CustomerName  |  CustomerId
```

**CustomerUpdate** table's structure

```
NewCustomerName  |   NewCustomerId  |  OldCustomerName
```

I have few values inserted in the `Customer` table. Whenever I should update the data in this table I want that the existing as well as new data should be triggered into new table `CustomerUpdate`.

For this I created a trigger but this is only pulling the updated data, it's not pulling the existing data..

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate 
ON [dbo].Customer 
FOR UPDATE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    declare @NewCustomerName nchar(20);
    declare @NewCustomerId nchar(20);
    declare @OldCustomerName nchar(20);
    declare @audit_action varchar(100);

    select @NewCustomerName = i.CustomerName from inserted i;   
    select @NewCustomerId = i.CustomerId from inserted i;   

    select @OldCustomerName = c.CustomerName 
    from Customer c 
    where CustomerId = @NewCustomerId;

    if update(CustomerName)
        set @audit_action='Updated Record -- After Update Trigger.';

    if update(CustomerId)
        set @audit_action='Updated Record -- After Update Trigger.';

    insert into  CustomerUpdate(NewCustomerName, NewCustomerId, OldCustomername) 
    values(@NewCustomerName, @NewCustomerId, @OldCustomerName);

    PRINT 'AFTER UPDATE Trigger fired.'
GO
```

Please help me out

Comment: Your trigger has a **MAJOR** flaw in that you assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. It will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statement affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `select @NewCustomerName = i.CustomerName from inserted i;` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: If you want the "old" values you need to use the deleted virtual table. Of course in a audit table it is redundant to include the new value. It will always be present in either the next audit row or the main table. It takes twice as much storage to store both values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, selecting from the table being modified when an update trigger is executing will get the new value. These are `AFTER` triggers (rather than `INSTEAD` triggers) and therefore the update has already happened by the time the trigger fires (although it can be rolled back).  If you need the old value, you should select from the `DELETED` pseudo-table.

Second, as pointed out by @marc_s in comments, your trigger has the hidden assumption that only one row is affected by each update.  This may very well be a valid assumption for your environment, if your application only ever updates one row at a time, but in the general case, every trigger should be ready to handle the case where many rows are affected by a single update. Writing your triggers to handle multiple rows is good practice.

Third, all of your sequentially executing code is pretty much unnecessary. The old value and the new value can be retrieved and inserted all at once:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate 
ON [dbo].Customer 
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    insert into  CustomerUpdate(NewCustomerName, NewCustomerId, OldCustomername) 
    -- case 1: ID unchanged
    SELECT I.CustomerName, I.CustomerID, D.CustomerName
    FROM Inserted I
    JOIN Deleted D on I.CustomerID=D.CustomerID
    UNION ALL
    -- case 2: ID changed, Name unchanged
    SELECT I.CustomerName, I.CustomerID, D.CustomerName
    FROM Inserted I
    JOIN Deleted D on I.CustomerName=D.CustomerName
    WHERE I.CustomerID<>D.CustomerID
    UNION ALL
    --case 3: ID changed, Name changed
    SELECT I.CustomerName, I.CustomerID, D.CustomerName
    FROM Inserted I
    LEFT JOIN Deleted D on I.CustomerID=D.CustomerID OR I.CustomerName=D.CustomerName
    WHERE D.CustomerID IS NULL;
END
```